# Modulo Behavior in C Left Shift Operation

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

The ISO C99 Standard for bitwise shift operators says the following in regard to left shift:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1×2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.

I don't understand what is meant when it says **"reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type"** in the context of shifting bits.

Comment: It's saying that if E1 * 2^E2 is too large to fit in the result type, then it is reduced using modulo arithmetic.  For example, if your result type was an unsigned 32b integer on a reasonable platform, then the above math will be reduced modulo 2^32.  (2^32 - 1) is the maximum value representable in the result type, so it will be reduced by that plus 1 (i.e. - 2^32).

Comment: It's a more complicated way to say that bits that don't fit in the result are chopped off.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically talking about [integer wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).  If the mathematical value is bigger than the max representable value of the type, then it wraps, i.e. *modulo arithmetic*.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value representable in the result type will have all of its bits set, which not a single power of two. However, the number against which the modulo operation is done (when the value starts to wrap) is a power of two, namely the next one, which can be obtained by adding one to the largest representable value.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to think about this is by looking at binary representation of what is going on.

When is states that **the value of the result is E1×2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type**. You can think of it like the following

Let us use an unsigned char which is an 8-bit type and has a maximum value 255

```
unsigned char ch = UCHAR_MAX
// ch : 255 : 1111 1111
```

Now let us left shift the value by one and also allow ourselves the ability to go beyond 8-bits (let us add another 4-bits)

```
ch = ch << 1;
// ch : 510 : 0001 1111 1110
```

We cannot store our 12-bit sudo number inside an unsigned char, so we need to keep the information that still fits and a way to do this is to modulo reduce by UCHAR_MAX + 1. Why UCHAR_MAX + 1 you may ask, well UCHAR_MAX + 1 looks like the following

```
UCHAR_MAX 
// 255 : 1111 1111

UCHAR_MAX + 1 
// 256 : 0001 0000 0000
```

So when we take our value that has exceeded its limits and modulo it by UCHAR_MAX + 1 we end up stripping all binary digits above our allowed 8-bit value.

```
ch % (UCHAR_MAX + 1)
// 510 % 256 = 254
// 0001 1111 1110 % 0001 0000 0000 = 1111 1110
```

Providing the expected result of shifting `ch << 1` which is what C will output.

At a computational level, this is not going to happen as we cannot arbitrarily just exceed are allowed size, so left shifting 1 beyond the maximum value causes a wrap-around which changes the least significant bit to 0.

I hope this helps along with the other answers that have already been provided for this question!